# Redshift copy from s3 Timestamp Format issues

Tags: amazon-redshift, time-format

I am copying a file with few records from S3 it is failing to load timestamp column.
Timestamp column value is '2000-00-00 00:00' and I mentioned as

```
COPY SampleLoad from 's3://folder/file.txt' delimiter '\t' IGNOREHEADER 1
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=;aws_secret_access_key=' 
timeformat AS 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI';
```

the error I get is 'invalid timestamp format or value YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI

One thing I noticed it doesn't fail until about line 15. this is where the '2000-00-00 00:00' time starts showing up in the data. Am I doing something wrong or can AWS not handle this value?

Answer (score 0):

oh, the time '2000-00-00 00:00' doesn't exist.

Comment: You could use ACCEPTANYDATE to include invalid formats.